# My Neural Network Doesn't Work [XOR problem]

Tags: c++, neural-network, xor, backpropagation, feed-forward

I'm trying to make a neural network for solving XOR problem.But I couldn't make it.Always giving false results.Maybe I'm making a mistake in your math.The network does not learn.Result always similarly.

I am not using BIAS.

```
Note: execute function = (feed-forward + backpropagation)
ALPHA = 0.5
```

Here is the code:

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "neural_network.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 srand(time(NULL));

 double array[][3] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
                      {0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
                      {1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
                      {1.0, 1.0, 0.0}};


neural_network* nn = new neural_network(3, 2, 2, 1, 1.0);
nn->create_network();

for(int i = 0; i < 15000; i++)
{
    int index = rand() % 4;
#if DEBUG
    std::cout<<"Inputs :"<<array[index][0]<<" , "<<array[index][1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Outputs :"<<array[index][2]<<std::endl;
#endif    
    nn->execute(array[index], &array[index][2]);
}

nn->print_weight();

nn->execute(array[0], &array[0][2]);
nn->print_output();

nn->execute(array[1], &array[1][2]);
nn->print_output();

nn->execute(array[2], &array[2][2]);
nn->print_output();

nn->execute(array[3], &array[3][2]);
nn->print_output();

return 0;
}
```

//feed-forward function

```
void neural_network::feed_forward(double* inputs)
{
int index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < neural_network::input_layer_size; i++)
    neural_network::input_neuron[i] = inputs[i];

for(int i = 0; i < neural_network::hidden_layer_size; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < neural_network::input_layer_size; j++)
    {
        neural_network::hidden_neuron[i] += neural_network::input_neuron[j] * weight_I_H[index++];
    }
    neural_network::hidden_neuron[i] = neural_network::activation_func(neural_network::hidden_neuron[i]);
}    

index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < neural_network::output_layer_size; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < neural_network::hidden_layer_size; j++)
    {
        neural_network::output_neuron[i] += neural_network::hidden_neuron[j] * weight_H_O[index++];
    }
    neural_network::output_neuron[i] = neural_network::activation_func(neural_network::output_neuron[i]);
}
```

}

//backpropagation function

```
void neural_network::back_propagation(double* outputs)
{
    int index;

for(int i = 0; i < neural_network::output_layer_size; i++)
    neural_network::err_output[i] = (outputs[i] - neural_network::output_neuron[i]);

for(int i = 0; i < neural_network::hidden_layer_size; i++)
{
    index = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < neural_network::output_layer_size; j++)
    {
        neural_network::err_hidden[i] += neural_network::weight_H_O[index] * neural_network::err_output[j] * neural_network::derivative_act_func(neural_network::output_neuron[j]);
        neural_network::weight_H_O[index] += ALPHA * neural_network::err_output[j] * neural_network::derivative_act_func(neural_network::output_neuron[j]) * neural_network::hidden_neuron[i];
        index += neural_network::hidden_layer_size;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < neural_network::input_layer_size; i++)
{
    index = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < neural_network::hidden_layer_size; j++)
    {
        neural_network::weight_I_H[index] += ALPHA * neural_network::err_hidden[j] * neural_network::derivative_act_func(neural_network::hidden_neuron[j]) * neural_network::input_neuron[i];
        index += neural_network::input_layer_size;
    }
}
}
```

//output

```
Input To Hidden :
H-1 :
    Weight :-13.269
    Weight :-13.2705
H-2 :
    Weight :-12.5172
    Weight :-12.5195

Hidden To Output :
O-1 :
    Weight :-5.37707
    Weight :-2.93218


Outputs for (0,0):
    O-1 :0.0294265

Outputs for (0,1):
    O-1 :0.507348

Outputs for (1,0):
    O-1 :0.62418

Outputs for (1,1):
    O-1 :0.651169
```

Comment: @JackGiffin is right in the point that questions, that are off-topic [(see here for that)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) will be closed. But there is no need to hurry at all, if that really is the case you still can copy your question without problems.

Comment: @JackGiffin Please don't recommend sites you aren't familiar with. This question is perfectly appropriate here, but not for Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

It is real impossible no keras no my developed net based on Furye transformation(which is more power than keras) real decide this XOR task.I tested very accuracy both of this ANN.Maximum the recognize is 3 examples of 4 (acc=0.75->75%).No one answered 1 xor 1=0.It seems nowbody realy tested this case seriosly.(ANN were multilayered)